# float value looses data after converting from double

Tags: c#, type-conversion

I have a double var represnting the seconds passed since 01/01/1900 from an ntp server and it prints ok

```
3616290958.594
3616290959.611
3616290960.538
```

I tried to convert it to a float in different methods like System.Convert.ToSingle and regular casting but I always get

```
3,616,291,000.00
```

I print the float using it's .ToString("N") method if it makes a difference

I even tried converting the double to a long, then the long to the float (I don't need any precision data after the dot, I'm going to floor the double before converting anyway).

nothing works, help.

Comment: You should add a code snippet, which produces the output you are showing, starting from a sample of actual data you receive from the ntp server.

Comment: Floats have a maximum precision of 7 digits. If we knew why you needed to convert it to a float, maybe we could find an alternate solution?

Comment: I use unity playerprefs to save it as the last time the user played the game, and playerprefs can only save float, int and string

Comment: You could either use the solution NeverHopeless posted below (storing the string only), or you could store a DateTime object instead, which you then convert to a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Math.Truncate`

Example:

```
Double d = 3616290958.594;
string k = Math.Truncate(d);
```